# RMI rebind JRMP error

Tags: java, rmi, policy, codebase

Since a few days i get the following error when I try to run my java server application:

```
SEVERE: Stratego server exception: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

My main method looks like:

```
Stratego stratego = new Stratego();
try
{
    if (System.getProperty("java.security.policy") == null)
    {
        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "src/Server/Policy/server.policy");
    }
    if (System.getProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase") == null)
    {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", "file:/D:/.../build/classes");
    }
    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
    { 
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
    }
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(9292);
    Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:9292/StrategoServer", stratego);

    Logger.getLogger(Stratego.class.getName()).info("Stratego server ready");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Logger.getLogger(Stratego.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Stratego server exception: {0}", e.toString());
    }
```

The policy, codebase and SecurityManager are new but when i comment them out, I still get this error. It all worked well before.
Can anyone tell me why?

Oh btw, I use Windows 7 x64 and JDK 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the port was occupied (don't know how). When I changed the port from 9292 to 9288 it worked.